# MySQL table size: Do I need to adjust something?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an InnoDB table which looks like this right now:

[image: MySQL Table Header]

[image: Table Size]

The table is around 126GB big, but I have read that InnoDB's default can hold up to 64 TB of data. Is this correct?

I ask because of the column "Data Free" which is very small compared to "Data Length" and soon will be 0 I guess.

Do I need to do something here? I mean 126GB is nothing compared to 64 TB.

Does MySQL manage this all by itself?

Comment: Hello, I'm almost sure that it would be better to back up the entire database and read it again. I know that this can be a very time-consuming project. It looks like you only have one InnoDB file. This is not particularly performant. Check your my.init to see if **innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_file_format = barracuda** is set like this. If you have to adjust this from 1, further parameters need to be adjusted. A file would then be created for each table (with **CREATE TABLE**, which would then be handled separately by MySQL. IMPORTANT!: Please read the necessary documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Besides having (maybe) only 1 InnoDB file, is there any problem besides performance? Will I run out of storage because of that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BerndBuffen - I just talked to the support and I confused the column "Data Free" with "what is actually free in the file". I have the Barracuda setting and I can save up to 64TB. So everything is fine :-)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Answer (score 0):

This was to long for comment:

Yes, there are big problems with performance if you only have one file. In the low level, MySQl uses the file handles from the system and only one process can write to a file. If you have a file for each table, mysql occupies 3 or 4 handles per table. This makes it much easier (for the system) to expand a table. There is also a file handle cache that needs to be adjusted. If there are no free file handles left (because they are not defined enough), MySQL has to close another table when reading or writing a table, open the new one and can then work with it. However, if the old table needs to be used again in the next query, the same thing happens in reverse. And these system calls, like open and close file, take a very long time to access.

Furthermore, MySQL NEVER releases disk space once it has been used. Although it is used again internally, everything on the disk remains the same.

Furthermore, if an error occurs, it is easier to recover a table than a monster file with all tables.

Since you have a lot of disk space, you can adjust the options in the ini and then copy the tables and copy them back with CREATE TABEL, then the new tables will be created as individual files.

You will be amazed at the speed gain you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Data_free` is not a finite resource that will run out. It's only a count of the extents (1MB contiguous space) that has already been allocated in the physical file, but which contains no data.

InnoDB tablespaces usually are configured to auto-expand. The default in current versions of MySQL is to store data in a file-per-table manner, and all such tablespaces are auto-expanding. That means if `data_free` runs out, InnoDB increases the size of the file incrementally until your storage runs out of space.

When a file-per-table or general tablespace expands, it increases by small amounts initially, then by 4MB increments.

Also as you UPDATE and DELETE data, it can leave gaps in pages of your tablespace. Once these gaps cover whole extents, they are counted in the `Data_free` figure for that tablespace. So the `Data_free` can increase and decrease from time to time, even if the physical file isn't growing.

InnoDB can *address* up to 64TB in a tablespace, but at least with current-generation servers, your storage is probably a lot smaller than that. You'll fill your storage much sooner than you will exceed InnoDB's addressable space.

There is one way that `Data_free` can be like a countdown to running out of space: if you store data in the system tablespace (`ibdata1`) by setting `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`, **AND** you have configured a system tablespace with a `max` size. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html#innodb-startup-data-file-configuration for details on that. If that tablespace fills up, then you can't store any more data. But neither of these configurations I mention are the default.